# Minimise File Size for Decimal .csv file

Tags: c#, ascii, filesize

I need to fit as much information as I can into a small file size. In this case, the data is in a comma separated format and all values are stored as 2dp decimals (no titles).

I've had a look and my understanding is that all the characters I need are stored using ASCII (1 byte per character) in my standard .txt file that I am currently using. Apparently ASCII has 256 possible values, which is way more than I need - I could get by with only 16 characters.

Could I save my data in some kind of 4bit text file? I will be creating the file using c# (all google searches result in advice on making a text file, not how to make a smaller "font" text). Would doing this save any space in the end anyway? 
I could zip up anything before I send it, but any advice on ideas to get the filesize down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing you could do is multiply your values by 100 to get rid of all of the decimal points.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like Protocol Buffers, Thrift, or MessagePack. or just pack to binary data.

Comment: It's not going to get any smaller without changing the format (or using compression, which does arguably change the format). Why do you need it to be a CSV file? If you stored it as a binary file, it could certainly get a lot smaller. But if you're interoping with some other application that expects CSV, then any attempt to make it smaller will prevent that other app from reading it.

Comment: Could you zip the file?

Comment: You can easily programmatically zip the data, so I would suggest doing that rather than trying to come up with your own compression format. Of course, then it is no longer a CSV file, and if you're going to make that kind of change, why not go further and store the file as binary numbers before compressing?

Comment: I can and will zip the file, but figured I should get it as small as possible before I do. I did not know about using a binary file - that's certainly something I will Google, thanks.

Comment: I had no idea that the commas and decimal points were likely to be the things taking up the space - so if i went for fixed width instead of csv, and made the file a single stream of digits, that would help?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter who will read the file? A human or some piece of software that you control?

Comment: The most compact format is binary.  Saving 2dp is floating point which is 4 bytes binary for single precision.  You can use :  BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal).  Then just write bytes to a file using BinaryWriter.

Comment: Seriously, if you want a small CSV - just zip it. It will be very repetitive text. It will zip really well. You get all the benefits of a standard format (CSV) and all the benefits of a small file (ZIP).

Comment: @usr it will be read by a piece of c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the question is legitimate, but the answer is that you impose logical conditions that leave no place for any solution.

So if you could avoid CSV structure for your custom structure you could save something, but you need it and it pretty much determines your solution. The only variable left is how do you encode the text, but you can't encode the text in less than 8 bits, you can just use higher values like Unicode (16 bits).

I won't comment on using compression as you already mentioned that you are looking for alternative answers and you are aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

> [the file] it will be read by a piece of c# code

You are therefore controlling the serialization format. You can pick any format you like.

A quick way to save space and reuse your existing code is to compress the CSV. Gzip is built-in but it is rather weak. You can use a 7-Zip library. The 7-Zip algorithm is state of the art. If will get rid of the redundancies caused by decimal points and by mostly using the characters 0-9. It will not remove 100% of that but 99%(?).

You can make this even more efficient by using a better format. You can use `BinaryReader/Writer` to easily write something entirely custom.

Protocol Buffers is a bit easier and also extremely compact.